# What Return Type? For "Getter" Functions Containing LINQ-to-SQL Which Return Many Rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I am developing an ASP.NET (VB.NET) Web Forms website which retrieves data from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Previously I would write LINQ-to-SQL code in the code-behind files. However, I wish to contain all of my LINQ-to-SQL code in **shared functions in "helper" classes** from now on.

I understand that if I am returning **only one row** then my function signature can be as follows:

```
Public Shared Function GetMainBanner(pageId as Integer) As MainBanner
```

But what if I am returning **zero or many rows?** Which of the following is **appropriate / cheapest**:

```
Public Shared Function GetRelatedDls(pageId as Integer) As List(Of RelatedDl)

Public Shared Function GetRelatedDls(pageId as Integer) As IQueryable(Of RelatedDl)

Public Shared Function GetRelatedDls(pageId as Integer) As IEnumerable(Of RelatedDl)

'OR SOMETHING ELSE?
```

My initial preference would be `List(Of RelatedDl)` purely because of readability, and IQueryable (I think, but may be wrong) hits the database many times if I call `.Count` and `.First` and do a `For Each`? And database interaction is **expensive,** no?

Given the following:

- Most of my entities have properties mapped to `nvarchar(50)` or `int` or `bit`
- Two of my entities have a property mapped to `nvarchar(MAX)`
- My "getter" functions will return roughly 5 - 25 rows at a time
- In processing an ASPX page request, roughly 10 - 20 "getter" functions will be called
- The website it running on a moderately powerful Windows 2008 server

**Which is the best choice or is there an alternative not listed above?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return it as IQueryable your db query will not be executed once you return from the function call and if your DataContext is in the function you will encounter a runtime error that the connection to you database is closed (once the data context is out of scope) once you try to use the query result.

If you return it as IEnumerable (List, Array.. etc..). Once you return the function call the objects will be loaded in memory.

It is up to you design to decide which approach is better and more eficient. If you are going to extend the query(add filter for example) from the calling method IQueryable is better since the extended query will be performed on a database level and you will load less data.